# Different menu layout Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a main application layout for Rails 4 with a navigation menu.

Also I have a nested routes like this.

- Admin <----- Admin menu

  - Company <----- Company menu

    - Client Company

      - Cliente Project <----- Project menu

        - sections

I need to have the different navbar items in these different parts.

I must create a layout for different groups of controllers?

```
layout :admin_layout
layout :Company_layout
layout :Project_layout
```

or I can create some kind of

```
if project == project
 show project links
esle
 .... 
end
```

any help on best practice for this. thanks.

**UPDATE**

Ok This post [Link](http://pothibo.com/2014/04/contextual-menus-with-yield-and-content_for/) got a solution put the problem that I found its not Dry.

Comment: The best practice is definitely not to have a new layout for each different page. You need to write a bit of dynamic code to build your menu.

Comment: @meagar  Create a single menu with all the items and use if for difrentes sections?. maybe?